# VS IDE can build, but run "dotnet build" command then got ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, dotnet-build

My visual studio pro 2019 is v16.11.2. I can build my mvc project without any issue by pressing build button, and run this project very well. Of cause, I've installed .net sdk 5.0.400 on my win10

[image]

Currently I'm studying docker, so I need to run command to build my project.

> dotnet build "MVConDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

unfortunately it failed.

> error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for
> ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cul0.png)

In global.json file, it's 5.0.400.

Comment: Somehow you managed to target .NET Framework 5.0, which doesn't exist. The latest version of framework is 4.8. I think you meant to target .NET 5.0

Comment: Do you have a reference that is not compatible with .NET 5.0?

Comment: Please use text for text, not images. See [ask] for more tips on asking good questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-versions for the correct values to put in the CSPROJ file (although VS2019 should be setting that for you).

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the project file?